# system with parameters

Tags: parametric

[image]

So our teacher gave us some things to work on, he said we should try to find out how to solve these tasks, but I'm the worst at math, I tried to think of something and failed. I'd appreciate some help!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you solve a similar system without parameters? If for example we let $a=b=1$ can you tackle this?

Comment: The two equations represent 2 straight lines. A solution means that they meet. Geometrically, what do (a), (b) and (c) mean then? Can you "see" how a and b relate for parts for (b) and (c)?

Comment: A useful first step would be to multiply the second equation through by $18$.

Comment: Hey everybody, thank you for your help! I now have figured it out, thanks to your tips:)